# Python-why does it print out "dessert"

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm new to programming, and obviously I can easily run a program to get the answer, but I want to get a clearer and better understanding of why this code runs "dessert". I understand len(s) is the length of the number, but what about the three numbers "-1, 0 -1"? Can I get a detailed explanation of why this prints dessert?

```
s = "stressed"

for i in range(len(s)-1, 0, -1):
    print(s[i], end = " ")
```

Comment: There's a documentation for [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s t r e s s e d

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

range function :  range(start, stop, step)

len(s) = 8

len(s-1)= 7

the loop starts at 7 stops at 0 and counts(steps) bacwards by 1 (-1)
so , the loop prints

7 6 5 4 3 2 1

d e s s e r t

Answer (score 1):

The code creates a range that counts *down*. Starting at `len(s) - 1` (so 7, `stressed` is 8 characters long), it'll count *down* to `1` (the end point is not included). In other words, you are giving `range()` three arguments, `len(s) - 1` is one argument, `0` is the second and `-1` is the third, and they represent the start, stop and step arguments. See the [`range()` type documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

The code then uses those values to index `s`; `s[7]` is the last character in the string, `d`, then `s[6]` is the one-but last character `e`, etc.

Breaking this down to the components in an interactive session:

```
>>> s = "stressed"
>>> len(s)
8
>>> len(s) - 1
7
>>> list(range(7, 0, -1))
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> s[7]
'd'
>>> s[6]
'e'
>>> s[1]
't'
```

If you wanted the code to print out `desserts` (with the `s` at the end) then you need to adjust the `range()` to loop up to `-1`:

```
for i in range(len(s) - 1, -1, -1):
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about `range()`.

It's all discussed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

It can be used in three ways;

```
range(stop)
range(start, stop)
range(start, stop, step)
```

Where in the first case, it will give `[1, 2, 3, ... stop-1]`, in the second case `[start, start+1, start+2, ... stop-1]`, and in the third case `[start, start+step, start+2*step, ...stop-step]`.

The thing to note here is that the `range` you get is `[start, stop)`. Where standard [interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29#Notations_for_intervals) has been used.

The other thing to note here is that step can be negative, which is what you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

```
range(len(s)-1, 0, -1)
reange(start_index, to_end_index, is_increment or is_decrement)
```

You call a loop with its start index, then tell it to traverse to end index and lastly increase the index or decrease the index

```
range(len(s)-1 *calculate the lengthof array (string), 0 *end point of traversing, -1 decrement the index)
```

If you use

```
range(0, len(s),1)
```

The loop will start from 0 index and traverse till last index with 1 index increment